# How can I tell CPAN::Shell to install all dependencies for a module?

Tags: perl, cpan

I currently have this on a script:

```
 CPAN::Shell->rematein("notest", "install", "$m");
```

Where $m is a module name the script installs. However, I want the module to install without prompting the user whether additional dependencies should be installed (optional deps or not), how can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

What is your setting for `prerequisites_policy` in CPAN::Config? That should be `follow` and not `ask`.

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/automatically-install-perl-dependencies-660847/).

Set `PERL_MM_USE_DEFAULT=1` in your environment.

Comment: Although this is not an idiot-proof solution: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=548581